# Where do you create application logs of app running in Docker?

Tags: scala, docker, logback, sbt-native-packager

Where do you create application logs of app running in Docker so that I can map them later to host system ?

It's unclear in [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) for me whether I should create logs in some directory accessible without root permissions (then which one?) or I somehow can chown directory I need.

I tried using `/var/log/case` and `/opt/case/logs` with no success. Here is my minified SBT script

```
object build extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "case-server",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ graphSettings ++ Revolver.settings ++ Seq(

      version := "1.15",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
      libraryDependencies ++= {
        val akkaV = "2.4.1"
        val akkaStreamV = "2.0.1"
        val scalaTestV = "2.2.5"
        Seq(
          "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",
          "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.+",
          "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestV % "test"
        )
      },

      dockerBaseImage := "develar/java",
      dockerCommands := dockerCommands.value.flatMap {
        case cmd@Cmd("FROM", _) => List(cmd, Cmd("RUN", "apk update && apk add bash"))
        case other => List(other)
      },
      dockerExposedVolumes := Seq("/opt/case/logs"),
      version in Docker := version.value
    )
  ).enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging).enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
}
```

What is the correct approach to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want your application log to be written on files on the container filesystem. The other solutions are:

- write log files to a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/)
- write log entries to `stdout` (so that they will be forwarded to the Docker engine and available with the [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command)

Furthermore, if your application is writing its log entries to `stdout`, you can rely on [Docker logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/logging/overview/) to send those logs to `syslog`, `journald`, `gelf`, `fluentd`, `awslogs`, json files, or any log collecting system that provides a docker logging driver.

A trick to make an application write to `stdout` instead of to a file is to configure it to write to the special file `/proc/self/fd/1`. Anything written to this special file will be sent to `stdout`.

Comment: I like idea of using docker drivers. How would you recommend effortlessly switching between awslogs and console output when I'm running the server directly on host machine in the debugger ? UPD: I just realized that perhaps `/proc/self/fd/1` would work on host too. Let me test now.

Comment: `/proc/self/fd/1` should work, just don't try to rotate that _fake_ file ^^

Answer (score 6):

From my POV you should think about not creating any log-file but use (unbuffered) stdout for logging in containerized environments.

Please see here for why this is a good idea http://12factor.net/logs

You can then use 'docker logs' to get the logs [like described here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/usingdocker/#viewing-the-web-application-s-logs)

Comment: Thank you! What I don't like about this approach is that log rotation logic would have to be performed by another service where currently `logback` takes case of that. All I need is to collect files.

Comment: log management should be pushed to the infrastructure (means docker) and by that can be setup once and made available to all your containers. you do not have to care about it, when you add more services .. or scale however else

Comment: see also here https://www.docker.com/press-release-12152015docker-unveils-new-ecosystem-technology-partners-log-management

Comment: @cybye Looks like awslogs is broken: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19392